# R: Loop through dataframes and re-assign factor levels

Tags: r, list, loops

I'm trying to set the same factor levels in 3 separate dataframes, so I tried to do so more efficiently via list and loop.

```
dlist <- list(d1, d2, d3)
for (i in 1:length(dlist)) {
  dlist[[i]]$myFactor <- factor(dlist[[i]]$myFactor, levels=c("l1", "l2"))
}
```

This seems to update the factor levels for copied dataframes in dlist, but not for the dataframes themselves.  How do I get d1$myFactor, d2$myFactor, d3$myFactor to change?

Comment: You've stumbled on a common R design issue. If you have `d1`, `d2` and `d3`, you essentially have 3 related objects. Consider that you put `column1`, `column2` and `column3` all in a `data.frame` called `d1` that can be looped over easily. You should similarly group up similar `data.frame`s in `dlist`, which you can then also loop over. (Or alternatively, join `d1/2/3` all into one long data.frame with an `id` column labelled which dataset they came from originally).

Answer (score 2):

When you put the data.frames in the list `dlist`, they are no longer linked to the original data.frames.  Updating values in `dlist` doesn't update values in `d1`, `d2`, or `d3`.

You should use `dlist` from here on out.  You can reference the individual elements (data.frames) with index values in the list.

If you want them back out of the list, you'll have to do so individually:

```
d1 <- dlist[[1]]
```